# How to automate Neo4j online backups creation

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to automate the process of creating online backups.
Could you please advice what is the best way of doing this?

One of the possible solutions is to create Java process, using Spring scheduler for example.
Using some time rule (cron expression) this process will invoke pretty simple Java code for creating online backups from Java:

```
File backupPath = new File("path to backup folder");
backupPath.mkdir();

OnlineBackup backup = OnlineBackup.from( InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() );
backup.full( backupPath.getPath() );
backup.incremental( backupPath.getPath() );
```

Is there any better or recommended way of automatizing online backups creating?

Thanks in advance,
     Denys

Comment: There is an executable that is includes(At least with the enterprise edition, not 100% about others) that you can call from the Command-Line that you could call through something like cron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `$NEO4J_DIR/bin/neo4j-backup` script. This script is a simple wrapper around the code in your question. Put this into a cron script or trigger it from your system's backup tool.

For docs, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/backup-embedded-and-server.html